# How do you hide the selectAll check box from clarity dataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity, selectall, clarity

How do you hide the selectAll check box from clarity dataGrid? Is it possible to use CSS to do that?

Comment: There were discussions about this on Github (https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2602) but Clarity doesn't support it so far because no valid use case for it has been presented for it yet. Removing a functionality for the user worsens the user experience, so what are your reasons for hiding it?

Comment: In our application, users are allowed to select up-to 3 records from the list in the datagrid when they perform comparison. We need to find a way to prevent them from selecting all records. If there is a way to hide/disable the SelectAll check box, this would satisfy our requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directives to disable select-all checkbox in datagrid.

Refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-datagrid-demo-h6kmh9